# How do I use this boolean. - isBlank

Tags: android, boolean

I'm a complete programming noob so go easy...

So I'm wondering how I would go about checking the edittext string to see if it "isBlank" using this isblank Boolean.

I know its probably a very easy answer but I just can't seem to get my head around it.
Any help appreciated.

```
public static boolean isBlank(String string) {

        if (string == null || string.length() == 0)
            return true;

        int l = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(string.codePointAt(i)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Thanks Heaps guys all helped alot!!..  If I could +1 I would.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?  It looks reasonable (though not ideal) to me.

Comment: Way to ask a question and ignore the responses John.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your method much shorter, like so:

```
static boolean isBlank(String string) {
    return string == null || string.trim().length() == 0;
}
```

The `trim()` method removes all whitespace characters from beginning and end of a string. If what remains has length == 0, the whole string must have consisted of whitespace only.

The usage in your code depends on your need, but generally you'll use it in `if()` statements to make the code more readable:

```
String foo = "... some string ...";
if (isBlank(foo)) {
    // foo is empty or only contains whitespace
} else {
    // foo contains some text.
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a separate method if Android id providing a default method.  `TextUtils.isEmpty(str.trim())`

Comment: @VishalVijay because str.trim() will cause a NPE if str is null.

Comment: @VishalVijay And because `isEmpty()` is API 9.

Comment: @Merlin its my mistake. I deleted my answer. @LuckyMe I'm not using `EditText.isEmpty()` it is `TextUtils.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this in single line.**

```
if(edittext.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
     Syste.out.println("Not Blank");
}else{
     Syste.out.println("Blank");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

Declare Class level variable:

boolean blank = false;

```
public static boolean isBlank(String string) {
        if (string == null || string.trim().length() == 0){
               blank = true;
        }
        else{
               blank = false;
        }
       return blank;
    }
```

Comment: fails for a null string.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if (isBlank(edittext.getText().toString())) {
    // Blank
} else {
    // Not blank
}
```

Comment: Who ever voted down is an idiot, re-read his question `how I would go about checking the edittext string to see if it "isBlank" using this isblank Boolean.` Basically he is asking how to use this function to check an EditText view content.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I will correct the problem created by anoter user:).